# "how to use 'image in span inside of li into a tag' and then fix height and with of span width class"

Tags: html, css

I want to fix height and width of `icon-block` class.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="javascript:"><span class="icon-block"><img src="image.png"></span>shop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="javascript:"><span class="icon-block"><img src="image.png"></span>customer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="javascript:"><span class="icon-block"><img src="image.png"></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can someone help me ?

Comment: can u add minimal working code ?

Comment: "https://jsfiddle.net/13b2mqLg/3/" kindly check fiddle link for get problem i face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something you need to understand here.

1. The `span` is a single line element and it cannot have `height` at all. So you can get the result by replacing the `span` by `div`
2. If you want the span element to take heights you can use `display:inline-block` to the `span` tag as i did so that you can set the `height` of the `span` as per your wish.(not compatible on all browsers though).

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.ul-block {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.icon-block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ul-block li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #ff0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul-block">
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <a href="javascript:"><span class="icon-block"><img src="https://compresspng.com/images/compresspng/icon.png"/></span>shop</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <a href="javascript:"><span class="icon-block"><img src="https://compresspng.com/images/compresspng/icon.png"></span>customer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">
    <a href="javascript:"><span class="icon-block"><img src="https://compresspng.com/images/compresspng/icon.png"></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @KhuramShahzad If the answer is correct accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to display that span first. E.g: set

```
    .list-inline-item span {
       display:block; 
       position:relative;
    }
```

after that, you can set the width or height that you want. :)

Comment: not working."this css push code to new line and image not containing in span tag"...